# The deleted comb space is connected and has two path components

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

The deleted comb space is the space obtained from the topologist's comb by deleting the open interval $\{0\} \times (0,1)$. I have to prove that the deleted comb space is connected and has two path components.

Can anybody help me? I need an idea.

Comment: Can you prove either part? It's not hard to see what the path components have to be.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have not been able to prove that it has 2 components

Comment: Is there a path from $\langle 0,1\rangle$ to any other point of the space?